# sendgrid how to track an individual email

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I am sending emails via sendgrid and would like to track the status of an email.

```
client = sendgrid.SendGridClient(username_or_apikey=my_key)
msg = sendgrid.Mail()
msg.add_to('a@foo.com')
msg.set_html('<div> hello there </div>')
msg.set_from('b@foo.com')
msg.set_subject('test sendgrid subject')
resp = client.send(msg)
```

The response object I am getting back is simply `(200, '{"message":"success"}')`. I was hoping to get back some for of email id.

I know sendgrid has [webhooks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html), but how do I associate a `sg_message_id` with an email that I sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate unique arguments on a per mail basis that go into the SMTP API JSON string and are included in status messages to webhooks.

Updated documentation URL from Todd M's answer:

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header

(Old Docs URL) More info at this page: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html

Comment: What if i send the mail by Web API v2, is it have a way to set the unique_arguments ?

Comment: it doest't have any data for setting status messages in the webhooks, the mentioned url is just a refernce to send an email.

Comment: Here's a better URL pointing to SG's doc about adding unique arguments via the X-SMTPAPI header: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header